# I have a resource who will work all day Tuesday, Wednesday & Thursday and a Friday morning every week, Can I set him up as one calendar entry?

Tags: ms-project

It seems as though I can't set full days and part days in one go?

I've created a new Calendar from the standard calendar and can assign the full days but cannot see how I would split that one day in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your new calendar, no exceptions needed.  Check [Default] Details on the Work Weeks tab. Make Monday a non-work day, then delete the second shift on Friday. Done.

[image]

Comment: In my head, I was over-engineering this! Works perfectly. Thanks.